# 2 level sort awk array

Tags: awk, columnsorting

I have this input file below where field separator ir "+" that I want to sort in 2 level. First by 3rd field and then by 2nd field in ascending order.

Input

```
240x151+140+624
240x151+462+176
240x151+87+257
240x151+366+355
240x151+77+448
240x151+468+542
178x59+223+65
178x59+417+65
178x59+611+65
178x59+29+65
110x16+255+63
```

My code I have so far is below but the output is not what I need.

```
awk '{split($0,f,"+")
      a[$0]=f[3];
     }END{
          n=asorti(a,b)
          for (i=1;i<=n;i++) 
          print b[i]}' file.txt
110x16+255+63
178x59+223+65
178x59+29+65
178x59+417+65
178x59+611+65
240x151+140+624
240x151+366+355
240x151+462+176
240x151+468+542
240x151+77+448
240x151+87+257
```

The expected output i'd like to get is like below and be able to handle the array based on numerical indices.

```
110x16+255+63  
178x59+29+65   
178x59+223+65  
178x59+417+65  
178x59+611+65  
240x151+462+176
240x151+87+257 
240x151+366+355
240x151+77+448 
240x151+468+542
240x151+140+624
```

Comment: to do this in `awk` create a new key by combining 3rd and 2nd fields and sort by that key.  However, you don't need to do this since `sort` is already designed to handle these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` is the right tool for this

```
$ sort -t+ -k3n -k2,2n file

110x16+255+63
178x59+29+65
178x59+223+65
178x59+417+65
178x59+611+65
240x151+462+176
240x151+87+257
240x151+366+355
240x151+77+448
240x151+468+542
240x151+140+624
```

one way to do this in `awk` by creating a new key by combining 3rd and 2nd fields and sort by that key.  Note however that array indices will be sorted non-numerically. So, we have to convert them into a text sorted equivalent format by zero padding.  Assuming the largest number has 5 digits (if not change accordingly).

```
$ awk -F+ '{k1=sprintf("%05d",$3); k2=sprintf("%05d",$2); a[k1,k2]=$0}
       END {n=asorti(a,d); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[d[i]]}' file

110x16+255+63
178x59+29+65
178x59+223+65
178x59+417+65
178x59+611+65
240x151+462+176
240x151+87+257
240x151+366+355
240x151+77+448
240x151+468+542
240x151+140+624
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've done with sort but since this is part of another script I need to pipe twice. First reading the file, then pipe to sort command and then pipe to awk again in order to handle the resulting sort output. I want to use a unique awk program for this. May you show me how would be combining field 3 and 2 as key?

Comment: Why do you think extra piping is a problem?  `awk` initially didn't have a `sort` function.

Comment: Excellent karakfa, nice very nice trick and combination with asorti(). Thanks a lot for the help. I asked 4 times how to do this and in 4th attempt you get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another (not perfect) using GNU awk and `asorti()`'s [*third string argument to control comparison of array elements*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html):

```
awk '
{
    split($0,f,"+")
    a[$0]=f[3]                    # a["110x16+255+63"] = 63
}
END {
    OFS=", "                      # for pretty output
    n=asorti(a,a,"@val_num_asc")  # NOTICE THE THIRD ARGUMENT, using asorti but "@val..."
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)            # "@ind..." would sort using the index
        print i,a[i]              # I wrote a over old a but you could use b
}' file
```

Output:

```
1, 110x16+255+63
2, 178x59+417+65
3, 178x59+611+65
4, 178x59+29+65
5, 178x59+223+65
6, 240x151+462+176
7, 240x151+87+257
8, 240x151+366+355
9, 240x151+77+448
10, 240x151+468+542
11, 240x151+140+624
```

Using `"@ind_num_asc"` the order would be:

```
1, 110x16+255+63
2, 178x59+223+65
3, 178x59+29+65
4, 178x59+417+65
5, 178x59+611+65
6, 240x151+140+624
7, 240x151+366+355
8, 240x151+462+176
9, 240x151+468+542
10, 240x151+77+448
11, 240x151+87+257
```

Comment: Hi James. Excellent. Even simpler solution. I understand how in first level is sorted the 3rd field, but I don't see clearly how is sorted equally ascending the 2nd field.

Comment: I talked too soon. It seems your solution still doesnt print the output desired.